Table with start end end time column to print signal in step format in VEGA Lite
i have a table with 3 columns



event
start-time
end-time




Active
2024-02-27T06:20:00.000Z
2024-02-27T06:23:28.630Z


Inactive
2024-02-27T06:23:28.000Z
2024-02-27T06:23:42.430Z



I would like to have a line plot to have a step-like diagram in which the event is plotted from start- to end-time.
I am only finding solution for x-axis with one column which contains the timestamp of a value.
Here i need to somehow bring start- and end-time together.
How can i solve this?

Is this for PowerBI? Can you supply a spec, sample data or an idea of what your expected result looks like.

Yes this is for PowerBI. Example see in table above

What does the end result look like? Do you have other examples you have seen on the web?

the result should look like a step-signal curve.
https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/sites/kom/0401111.htm
However i have not find any example from vega-lite. I am not sure if this is even possible since start end time for the rising and falling edge are in different columns. I maybe need to merge the two columns into one with twice the amount of rows.

You can use vega-lite's fold function to prepare the data accordingly within Vega-lite.
{
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"start": "2024-01-01", "end": "2024-01-02", "event": "Active"},
      {"start": "2024-01-02", "end": "2024-01-03", "event": "Inactive"},
      {"start": "2024-01-03", "end": "2024-01-04", "event": "Active"},
      {"start": "2024-01-04", "end": "2024-01-05", "event": "Inactive"}
    ],
    "format": {
      "parse": {
        "start": "date", "end": "date"
      }
    }
  },
    "transform": [
    {"fold": ["start", "end"]} 
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "value", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "event", "type": "ordinal"}

  }
}

which yields this:

For some reason it is necessary to explicitly parse the start and end columns as date if you want to have the x axis as temporal. If you are fine with nominal, then you do not need the format section.
Try it in the Vega online editor
